# Force custom aspect ratio in software (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, external-display, aspect-ratio

I am using a 10inch laptop screen with an HDMI interface from ebay. Across all available resolutions the aspect ratio is distorted, IE. circles on the screen apear as elipses some vertical, others horizontal. Its manual controls contain the option to change the aspect ratio but none of them function. I have an AMD Radeon RX 560. I am an architecture student and the ability to accurately display proportions is very important to the displays function.

Comment: Have you checked the vendors site for the native resolution for your display? Do you have the latest drivers installed for the video card?